# Assign unique groups to multiple duplicates in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you can help me with below logic problem.

I have a list of various duplicates that I need to assign unique group (same group name for same duplicate values). Tricky part is, that names are in random order, plus there are bunch of unique names in between.

I would prefer non VBA solution, but would accept it as well. Thank you!

Many thanks!

[excel work sample](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=73731359489219288989)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have revisited the problem and found a solution. Probably over complicated, but it does its job. Logic is as follows:

1. Create unique list of all groups
   Formula(Array):

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$20, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $B$2:$B$20), 0)),"")`

2. Create unique list with only values that have more than 1 record

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(D2,$B$2:$C$20,2,FALSE)=1,"",VLOOKUP(D2,$B$2:$C$20,1,FALSE)),"")
```

3. Assign unique group number for each value

Formula:

```
=IF(E2="","",LARGE($F$1:$F1,1)+1)
```

Unfortunately can't attach image due to lack of reputation, so [attaching excel sample instead](http://www.datafilehost.com/d/74df432d).